# Insert dynamic controls after page_load (ViewState persistent)

Tags: c#, controls, viewstate, persistent

I have a page where I create a dynamic table, containing dynamic controls which raise events.
It works, but I wan't to re-generate that table in some events (so after page_load) to print table modifications.

I understand the problem, its that at this moment, my controls aren't persisted in the viewstate because they are created after page_load, and their events are not raised. But how could I do this ?

Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    generateTable(); // When pass just here, it works well
}

private void generateTable()
{
    Table tbl = new Table();
    // Here I create my table with controls

    tableContainer.Controls.Clear(); // tableContainer is a Panel fixed in aspx page
    tableContainer.Controls.Add(tbl);
}

protected void txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do some stuff to change values in the table
    generateTable(); // Re-generate (but events will not be raised)
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I thought about something (which complicate my development), but I should do generateTable which creates all my lines and controls and call it on each page_load. And in the other hand create another method which populate controls ? So in events, I call the second one.

But my table is generated dynamically, and controls can also be added after an event (I have a dropdownlist which create a new line and control in the table, so I'm stuck also here cause I won't see the line at the first postback ?)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a really good link that describes management of dynamically added controls: https://web.archive.org/web/20050321094957/http://devcenter.infragistics.com/Articles/ArticleTemplate.ASPX?ArticleID=2149

Note that once you add the control in your ASP.NET backend anywhere, you have to set property

```
ViewState["AddedControl"] = "true";
```

Also, during postback, your page will be regenerated so at that time you will have to re-create the control and set old values backs.

From the same link:

```
public void Page_Load() {
   if (IsPostBack) {
      if (ViewState["AddedControl"] != null) {
         // Re-create the control but do not
         // restore settings configured outside
         // the proc (i.e., MaxLength and BackColor)
         TextBox t = AddTextBox(); 
      }  
   }
}
public void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   TextBox t = AddTextBox();
 
   // Modify properties outside the proc to
   // simulate generic changed to the
   // control's view state
   t.MaxLength = 5;
   t.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
}

public TextBox AddTextBox() {
   TextBox ctl = new TextBox();
   ctl.Text = "Hello";
   placeHolder.Controls.Add(ctl);
 
   // Records that a dynamic control has been added
   ViewState["AddedControl"] = "true";
   return ctl;
}
```

Comment: Same problem with this, as I do not go through Page_Load after my event, and I do not see changes before another postback.

Answer (score 0):

You should generate your controls on the PageInit event instead. Controls generated on PageInit are automatically managed by the asp.net framework (you'll get viewstate persistance, raised events, etc...)

Just a side note: On your PageInit, you have to **always** regenerate the dynamic controls or the framework won't be able to manage them.

Try generating your controls on PageInit, and then changing their properties on the postback event like so:

```
List<LiteralControl> list = new List<LiteralControl>();

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    generateTable(); // When pass just here, it works well
}

private void generateTable()
{
    Table tbl = new Table();
    // Here I create my table with controls

    int rows = 3;
    int cols = 2;
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
    {
        TableRow r = new TableRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++)
        {
            TableCell c = new TableCell();
            LiteralControl l = new LiteralControl("row " + j.ToString() + ", cell " + i.ToString());

            // save a reference to the control for editing
            list.Add(l);

            c.Controls.Add(l);
            r.Cells.Add(c);
        }
        tbl.Rows.Add(r);
    }

    tableContainer.Controls.Clear(); // tableContainer is a Panel fixed in aspx page
    tableContainer.Controls.Add(tbl);
}

protected void txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // edit controls here
    foreach (LiteralControl ctrl in list)
    {
        ctrl.Text = "TextChanged";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but problem is that in some cases, I have to call generateTable() from an event, so after Page_Init and after Page_Load

Comment: Why do you have to call generateTable twice? Can you give me an example?

Comment: actually, my table contains some controls which raise events. In this events, I modify some values in an object stored in the viewstate, and that values are printed in the table. So when it changes on a postback event, I want to print it in the table, but I'm after the page_load and will have to refresh one time the screen to see it !

Comment: I call it twice because the first time it initializes my controls so that events can be raised, et the second time to actualize changes that occured in the event.

Comment: Just saw your edit, it would work but I have a case where I have to add a control IN the event, so this one will not be persisted in the first postback

Comment: Add the control in the PageInit method, but set it invisible. Then in the txt changed event set it visible.